# Hibernate mapping. Table related with other two

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the tables A and B related with the table shortcut but, I get this error

```
    org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table A refers to an unmapped class: Shortcut
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1112)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1062)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1146)
```

When I put a shortcut as null in a object A or B or I delete a object A or B and do save or delete the shortcut isn't deleted in the table shortcut.

I think that I have to set a relation in shortcut also but because there are two tables I don´t know how to do this.

```
table A
id - int - Primary key
description - String
.
.
**id_shortcut - int - Foreing key table shortcut - id**


table B
id - int - Primary key
description - String
.
.
**id_shortcut - int - Foreing key table shortcut - id**
```

table shortcut
    **id - int - Primary key**
    description - String

```
a.hbm.xml
.
.
<many-to-one cascade="all" class="Shortcut"  fetch="join" name="shortcut">
    <column name="ID_SHORTCUT" not-null="false"/>
</many-to-one>


b.hbm.xml
.
.
<many-to-one cascade="all" class="Shortcut"  fetch="join" name="shortcut">
    <column name="ID_SHORTCUT" not-null="false"/>
</many-to-one>
```

shortcut.hbm.xml

```
     <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="Shortcut" table="ris_SHORTCUT">
      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
       <column name="ID" sql-type="NUMBER(19)"/>
       <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">RIS_SHORTCUT_SEQ</param>
       </generator>
      </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="key1" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="KEY1" not-null="true" sql-type="VARCHAR2(20)"/>
      </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="key2" type="java.lang.String">
       <column name="KEY2" not-null="true" sql-type="VARCHAR2(1)"/>
      </property>
     </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you sure `shortcut.hbm.xml` is actually included in your Hibernate configuration ?

Comment: yes, it's included, I have no problem with the entity A relation but the entity B send me this error

Comment: Shortcut is your master table and referenced as a foreign key in table A and B, you cannot delete shortcut by save,delete,update operation on table A or B since table A and B contains only the reference to shortcut. it will set null in A or B but won't delete shortcut, if you want to delete shortcut you have to use delete by passing shortcut object.

There is simple rule if you delete master you have options to delete child as well but reverse when you delete child you don't have option to delete master as well. you can consider this is relationship constraint.